# Looking for a way to run a Python script multiple times while converting txt files to csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert multiple txt files to csv.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib
path=pathlib.Path(folderpathtotxtfiles)
def create_csv(filename):
  try:
     df=pd.read_csv(filename,sep='\s+',on_bad_lines='skip')
     df.to_csv(f'{filename}.csv,header=None,index=False)
  except:
     print(filename,'is empty')
for filename in path.glob('*.txt'):
  create_csv(filename)
```

This gives me the required output,but is there anyway that I could run this code multiple times and each time it should only take 10 files from my path and convert it to csv. Like if I run it multiple times simultaneously it should take first 10 files then next 10 files and so on

Comment: You would need to move/delete/rename the source (.txt) files in order to ensure that you process different files each time you run the program. Or you could maintain a persistent store of files that have already been processed

Comment: Each text file is unique and I am able to convert it to csv but it takes too much time to do that.Thats why I wanted something like that it should take 10 files at a time and should run it simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

You need some way to ensure that files processed in one run of the program are not processed in second and subsequent invocations.

One way to do this is to create a directory to where you move the files that have already been processed. In that way they won't be "seen" on subsequent runs.

For optimum performance you should consider either multiprocessing or multithreading. In this case the former is probably most appropriate.

Something like this:

```
import pandas
import os
import sys
import shutil
import glob
import re
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

SOURCE_DIR = '/Volumes/G-Drive/src' # location of source files
SAVE_DIR = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, 'processed') # location of saved/processed files
BATCH_SIZE = 10
SUFFIX = 'txt'

def move(filename):
    try:
        os.makedirs(SAVE_DIR, exist_ok=True)
        target = os.path.join(SAVE_DIR, os.path.basename(filename))
        shutil.move(filename, target)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)

def create_csf(filename):
    try:
        df = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep=' ')
        csv = re.sub(fr'{SUFFIX}$', 'csv', filename)
        df.to_csv(csv, index=False)
        move(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=sys.stderr)

def main():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as ppe:
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, f'*.{SUFFIX}'))
        ppe.map(create_csf, list(files)[:BATCH_SIZE])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can modify your code to run multiple time and took 10 every time.

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

folder_path = pathlib.Path(folder_path_to_txt_files)

def create_csv(filename):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\s+', on_bad_lines='skip')
        df.to_csv(f'{filename}.csv', header=None, index=False)
    except:
        print(filename, 'is empty')

# Get the list of all txt files in the folder
file_list = list(folder_path.glob('*.txt'))

# Number of files to process at a time
batch_size = 10


while file_list:
    batch = file_list[:batch_size]  
    file_list = file_list[batch_size:]   

    
    for filename in batch:
        create_csv(filename)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This will process the same 10 files every time you run it